# Fastest way to read from sql server database using C#.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I' m developing a program, which need to read more up than 1 million of rows from an Sql Server Database. Currently I' m using this code:

```
        arr_hist = new TickByTick[0];
        SqlDataReader l_dr;
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM " + symb + " ORDER BY DT ASC, CumVol ASC";
        if (RunSelectCommand(cmd,out l_dr))
        {
            if(l_dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (l_dr.Read())
                {
                    nr_tick += 1;
                    Array.Resize(ref arr_hist, nr_tick + 1);
                    arr_hist[nr_tick].d_time = l_dr.GetDateTime(1);
                    arr_hist[nr_tick].price = l_dr.GetDouble(2);
                    arr_hist[nr_tick].bid = l_dr.GetDouble(3);
                    arr_hist[nr_tick].ask = l_dr.GetDouble(4);
                    arr_hist[nr_tick].Vol = l_dr.GetInt32(5);
                    arr_hist[nr_tick].CumVol = l_dr.GetInt32(6);
                }
            }
        }
```

But the problem is that it takes about one minute for 40k rows, while I would need to read 40k rows in 10 seconds.
Could you suggest how can I read fastly?
Thank you.

Antonio

Comment: Why do you need to create an array with a million items? There is no chance this is going to run fast. It is much more than just sql slowing this down. And I would suggest you not use select *. Also be EXTREMELY careful here. You are passing in the table name which is incredibly dangerous. At the very least you need to wrap the table name with QUOTENAME to help minimize the risk of sql injection or errors if there are funky characters in the name.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data after you've loaded it? In many cases it is much faster to do this on the RDBMS. In this case you'd load some aggregated / computed / whatever rows instead of the whole lot.

Comment: I use the data to build chart. Thank you for answer. And I need to crete array, in which way I can elaborate data

Comment: If you really do need need get all the items available in memory, then at the very least use `List<T>` rather than `Array<T>` and using `Array.Resize` with each iteration. `Array.Resize` is a bit of a misnomer, it doesn't really resize the array, it creates a new array, and copies all the elements from the old one to the new one. This is probably your bottleneck. If you chart requires an array, you can just use `List.ToArray()` once it is populated.

Comment: Ok I try to use List. Maybe it' s the problem.

Comment: Use Parameterized SQL Queries, not string concatenation. This not only helps reduce the possibility of SQL injection attacks, but also reduces SQL plan cache pollution. Look into the use of SqlParameter to pass in your parameters.

Comment: I solved using List<T>. Now it takes 500ms for 150k rows. Thank you too much.

Comment: @pmbAustin while your comment is correct it's not applicable in this case since it's impossible to parameterize identifiers in sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to return that much records, Sql server is not good in doing sorting until and unless the data is already sorted within storage. So I think either you remove the order by or CREATE NON CLUSTERED INDEX on these columns DT ASC, CumVol ASC